# Problem With Export Button in Report Viewer 2010 Localization

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reporting-services, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I localized Report Viewr 2010 using Implement this Interfaces: `IReportViewerMessages,IReportViewerMessages2, IReportViewerMessages3`

every thing is ok and my desire labels appears in report viewer.but when I open Export list there is no item in it.

[image]

what is my fault and how I can fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is possible by implement `IReportViewerMessages2` and `GetLocalizedNameForRenderingExtension` method :

```
public string GetLocalizedNameForRenderingExtension(string format)
{
    switch (format.ToLower())
    {
        case "xml":
            return "your xml label";
        case "csv":
            return "your csv label";
        case "pdf":
            return "your pdf label";
        case "mhtml":
            return "your mhtml label";
        case "excel":
            return "your excel label";
        case "image":
            return "your image label";
        case "word":
            return "your word label";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well clearly you have not localized every single string and you should still add some missing localization.

You can fix this by checking if you should have been implementing another interface except those 3 you have already used, if you also have the neutral resource file you can compare it with your interfaces implementation and see if there is any missing key/string.